# VS is making this suggestion. Why does distinct appear twice?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, distinct-values

I have a question about a suggestion that Visual Studio makes me. I have a class-wide char array in which I place characters that are allowed for user input. That has already happened in this scenario. I don't want any character to appear multiple times, hence this code.

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Char) = erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct()
erlaubte_Zeichen = New Char(result.Count - 1) {}
erlaubte_Zeichen = result.ToArray()
```

VS is now making this suggestion for improvement. **Why does distinct appear twice?**

```
erlaubte_Zeichen = (New Char(erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct().Count - 1) {})
erlaubte_Zeichen = erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct().ToArray()
```

*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.1*

Comment: The first is being used to get the count of distinct values (that distinct result isn't actually being stored) while the second is being used as the basis for your array... `erlaubte_Zeichen = erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct().ToArray()` should suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS is giving you a bad suggestion because you have written bad code in the first place. In your original code, the middle line is completely pointless. The third line creates a new array and assigns it to the variable so the array you create and assign to the variable in the second line is simply discarded. This:

```vb
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Char) = erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct()
erlaubte_Zeichen = New Char(result.Count - 1) {}
erlaubte_Zeichen = result.ToArray()
```

can become this:

```vb
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Char) = erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct()
erlaubte_Zeichen = result.ToArray()
```

which means that it is ridiculously verbose and should be written like this:

```vb
erlaubte_Zeichen = erlaubte_Zeichen.Distinct().ToArray()
```

If you don't include useless code then VS won't provide suggestions to make that useless code more efficient.